# Which exception will Python throw when it does not have sufficent permissions to access the file?

Tags: python, linux

By permissions I mean unix-like filesystem permissions

I’m looking for a more accurate exception than OSError, which triggers also when the file does not exist

Comment: Why don't you try by yourself ? That's quite easy to test, isn't it ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers my question is malformed tbh, explanation below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok let me show you...

In Python 2.7.x:

=> this file does not exist:

```
>>> try:
...     open("foo.bar")
... except Exception as e:
...     e1 = e
... 
>>> e1
IOError(2, 'No such file or directory')
```

=> This one exists but I don't have permissions on it

```
>>> try:
...     open("/root/foo.txt")
... except Exception as e:
...     e2 = e
... 
>>> e2
IOError(13, 'Permission denied')
>>>
```

So here you cant test on `e.args[0]`, which is also accessible as `e.errno`

```
>>> e2.args[0]
13
>>> e2.errno
13
>>>
```

On Python 3.4.x

```
>>> try:
...     open("foo.bar")
... except Exception as e:
...     e1 = e
... 
>>> e1
*FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
>>> 

>>> try:
...     open("/root/foo.txt")
... except Exception as e:
...     e2 = e
... 
>>> e2
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

Here you have two distinct subclasses of `OSError`, so you can either setup two distinct except clauses, or - like in python2 but using `OSError` instead of `IOError` - use a single except and test `e.errno`.

And as you can see, testing this by yourself takes about 2 minutes, which is certainly **MUCH** less than it took you to connect to SO, post your question, answer comments, edit your question, etc etc etc...

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look to `IOError`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html

Comment: He should try by himself actually.

Comment: IOError is deprecated in this context, OSError is raised

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I’ve read the documentation and I’m looking for a way to distinct a „notexists”  case from „notenoughaccess” case because both throw OSError